# how to factorise makefile targets?

Tags: makefile

I have the following 'working' snippet:

```
c_file_path := toto.c
asm_file_path := toto.S

c_files = $(notdir $(c_file_path)) 
asm_files = $(notdir $(asm_file_path)) 

vpath %.c $(dir $(c_file_path)) 
vpath %.S $(dir $(asm_file_path))

OBJDIR=objs/
c_objs:=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR),$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(c_files)))
asm_objs:=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR),$(patsubst %.S,%.S.o,$(asm_files)))


$(info c_files $(c_files))
$(info s_files $(asm_files))
$(info c_objs $(c_objs))
$(info asm_objs $(asm_objs))

%.c:
    @touch $@
%.S:
    @touch $@

objs/%.o:%.c
    @mkdir -p  $(OBJDIR)
    @gcc -c $^ -o $@

objs/%.S.o:%.S
    @mkdir -p  $(OBJDIR)
    @gcc -c $^ -o $@

clean:
    @rm -rf objs/*
    
all: $(c_objs) $(asm_objs)
    @ls $(c_objs) $(asm_objs)
    @echo "hello"
```

I tried to merge targets:

```
c_file_path := toto.c
asm_file_path := toto.S

c_files = $(notdir $(c_file_path)) 
asm_files = $(notdir $(asm_file_path)) 

vpath %.c $(dir $(c_file_path)) 
vpath %.S $(dir $(asm_file_path))

OBJDIR=objs/
c_objs:=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR),$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(c_files)))
asm_objs:=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR),$(patsubst %.S,%.S.o,$(asm_files)))


$(info c_files $(c_files))
$(info s_files $(asm_files))
$(info c_objs $(c_objs))
$(info asm_objs $(asm_objs))


%.c %.S:
    @touch $@

objs/%.o objs/%.S.o:%.c %.S
    @mkdir -p  $(OBJDIR)
    @gcc -c $^ -o $@

clean:
    @rm -rf objs/*
    
all: $(c_objs) $(asm_objs)
    @ls $(c_objs) $(asm_objs)
    @echo "hello"
```

which gives:

```
gcc: error: toto.c no such file or directory
```

why weren't target merged?

### how to merge targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but this rule:

```
objs/%.o objs/%.S.o:%.c %.S
```

tells make that for two files `foo.c` and `foo.S` (for any string `foo`) they can be used to create the targets `objs/foo.o` and `objs/foo.S.o` by invoking the recipe (`gcc`) one time.

I'm pretty sure that that's not what you want to say because it means you can't use this pattern unless **both** files `foo.c` **and** `foo.S` exist for a given string `foo`.

If what you're asking is how to reduce these two pattern rules:

```
objs/%.o:%.c
        @mkdir -p  $(OBJDIR)
        @gcc -c $^ -o $@

objs/%.S.o:%.S
        @mkdir -p  $(OBJDIR)
        @gcc -c $^ -o $@
```

into a single pattern rule so you don't have to write it twice the answer is very simple:

You can't.

You could put the recipe into a variable, like this:

```
build = @mkdir -p  $(OBJDIR) && gcc -c $^ -o $@
```

then you can simplify the pattern rules somewhat like this:

```
objs/%.o : %.c ; $(build)
objs/%.S.o : %.S ; $(build)
```

but that's the best you can do, without resorting to overly-complicated things like `foreach`/`eval`/`call` loops etc.

Comment: I should say that if you were willing to name your `c` object files with a suffix `%.c.o`, rather than `%.c`, like your `S` object files are named `.S.o`, then you could try a single pattern rule of `objs/%.o : %` and that might work.

Comment: I tried this as well before your answer but i was getting and error.
I tried again and it's working. I think this is the best solution